# Obter conteúdo do atributo src na tag <img> via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer um campo senha, que ao clicar numa imagem ao lado dele, irá deixar a senha visível, e com isso também quero mudar a imagem quando ocorrer o click.

Meu HTML está assim:

```
 <img src="~/Imagens/olho.jpg" style="width:7%;" align="right" onclick="mostraSenha(this)" id="img"/>
```

Minha função javascript está assim:

```
<script>
        function mostraSenha(e) {
            var x = document.getElementById("senha")
            if (x.type === "password") {
                x.type = "text";
            } else {
                x.type = "password";
            }
            if ($(e).attr("src") == "/Imagens/olho.jpg") alterarImagem('img', "/Imagens/olho-fechado.jpg");
            else alterarImagem('img', "/Imagens/olho.jpg");

        }

        function alterarImagem(objeto, caminhoNovaImagem) {
            document.getElementById(objeto).src = caminhoNovaImagem;       
        }
    </script>
```

Estou tentando no "if ($(e).attr("src")" verificar o valor contido em src, porém isso não funciona. Tentei dar um window.alert mas também não abre nada.

Existe alguma maneira de verificar o conteúdo no meu atributo src? Isto é, verificar quando ele está como "/Imagens/olho.jpg" ou como "/Imagens/olho-fechado.jpg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você está efetuando uma verificação desnecessária. Você pode colocar essa condição assim que alterar o tipo do seu campo de texto:

```
<script>
    function mostraSenha(e) {

        var x = document.getElementById("senha")

        if (x.type === "password") {
            x.type = "text";
            alterarImagem('img', "/Imagens/olho-fechado.jpg");
        } else {
            x.type = "password";
            alterarImagem('img', "/Imagens/olho.jpg");
        }

    }

    function alterarImagem(objeto, caminhoNovaImagem) {
        document.getElementById(objeto).src = caminhoNovaImagem;       
    }

</script>
```

Apenas respondendo sua pergunta, para obter o valor de `src` da tag `img` utilize `document.getElementById('img').src`, assim como você utilizou para setar o valor em `alterarImagem`, ou com jQuery `$("img").attr("src")`. Talvez o motivo que não tenha funcionado é que a princípio você inseriu um `~` no caminho inicial. Veja um teste funcionando:

```js
function mostraSenha(e) {

    var x = document.getElementById("senha");
    
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
    
    if ($(e).attr("src") == "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e") {
      alterarImagem('img', "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg?v=62f619494ccd");
    }
    else {
      alterarImagem('img', "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e");
    }

}

function alterarImagem(objeto, caminhoNovaImagem) {
    document.getElementById(objeto).src = caminhoNovaImagem;       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="senha" value="testesenha">
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e" width="30" onclick="mostraSenha(this)" id="img"/>
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, era erro de lógica mesmo! A única coisa que tive que alterar foi a ordem, como inicio com a "/Imagens/olho.jpg", ela deve ficar no else da função, valeu! =)

Comment: Legal @Bruno! Que bom que ajudei! Alterei a resposta com o que você disse! :)

Answer (score 2):

Como sugestão, acredito que utilizar uma imagem para isso seja desnecessário. Várias fontes possuem caracteres que reproduzem a imagem do olho aberto e fechado; a própria tabela unicode possui o caractere `U+1F441` que é um olho que poderia ser utilizado:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('closed-eye');
  const input = $('input');
  input.attr('type', input.attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password');
});
```

```css
.closed-eye span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='password' value='senha super segura'>
<button><span>&#128065;</span></button>
```

Assim você não precisa carregar mais duas imagens e deixa a aplicação bem mais rápida.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo feedback, a questão é que estou utilizando ASP, por isso meu campo está da seguinte maneira:

<div class="form-group has-feedback">
     <img src="~/Imagens/olho.jpg" style="width:7%;" align="right" onclick="mostraSenha(this)" id="img"/>
     Html.PasswordFor(m => m.senha, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Senha", id = "senha", style = "max-width:290px; max-height:35px;", required = "required" })
</div>

Por isso fiz dessa maneira, porém vou tentar ajustar ver se funciona! Obrigado =)

Comment: Estou utilizando o padrão MVC, por isso precisei utilizar o "Html.AlgumAtributo" para fazer comunicação da minha View com meu Controller.